# Как прописывать FOREIGN KEY значение в INSERT INTO?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-key

Допустим есть:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id INTEGER,
    username TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE info (
    info_id INTEGER,
    information TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (info_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)  
)
```

И как прописать INSERT INTO для info?
Ведь если просто прописать

```
INSERT INTO info
VALUES (1, 'info if not defined')
```

То даже учитывая, что в таблице user нету пользователя с user_id 1 строка всё равно создастся и взаимосвязи нету.

Comment: разберитесь что на что ссылается сначала. а потом проверьте, действительно ли создатся.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для обеспечения обратной совместимости, по умолчанию, поддержка внешних ключей в SQLite отключена.

Если SQLite откомпилирована **без** опций `SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY` и `SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER` то поддержка внешних ключей включается командой

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

команда

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys;
```

покажет текущее состояние переменной.

Если при компиляции был определен параметр `SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER` то внешние ключи игнорируются вне зависимости от `PRAGMA foreign_keys`.

Если при компиляции был определен параметр `SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY` то конструкция `FOREIGN KEY (info_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)` будет вызывать ошибку парсинга.

[Первоисточник](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)